# Background image not displaying in the desktop after adding the parent div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am displaying a background image which is working on the desktop and mobile device.

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}

.about_header_bg{
    background-image: url('https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltada7771f270d08f6/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.banner_bg{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_header_bg banner_bg"></div>
```

Now What I did, I added 2 divs which are `header_relative` and `header_fixed`.

```
<div class="header_relative">
<div class="header_fixed">
 <div class="about_header_bg banner_bg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have to use `header_relative` and `header_fixed` in the mobile device, not on the desktop.
So I added media queries and added my CSS

```
    @media all and (max-width : 768px)  {
    .header_relative{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
     }
   .header_fixed{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    }
    }
```

After adding divs, In the mobile device background image is displaying but in the desktop, background image not displaying.

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: you need to keep height:100% of `hedear_relative` and `header_fixed` outside media query also ... if you don't do, the min-height:100% wont work (there is no reference)

Comment: .header_relative{height:100%;} .header_fixed{height:100%}  adding this   in the css will clear the issue i hope

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas, Yes It's working. Thanks for the help.